# XUL and document.write()

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm attempting to create a simple firefox extension and am stumbling on what I'm allowed to do in a XUL window.

I'd like to use document.write or get a handle on a textarea to collect data and display it when a button is clicked.

Are there any tutorials on how to do this? From what I've been reading, people have suggested opening a new window and writing to it, but my goal is a persistent window at the bottom of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple XUL application using xulrunner. Try this : http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2009/02/standalone-xul-application-translating.html

Later when your application will be correctly running you will transform it into an extension.

Hope it helps.